# Confused about Chebyshev and Empirical rule when applied to this question.

Tags: statistics

Here is the question I'm working on for my statistical methods class:

Given a data set with a largest value of $760$ and a smallest value of $135$, what would you estimate the standard deviation to be?

I used Chebyshev's rule to figure out that $8/9$ of the measurements will fall w/in $3$ standard deviations of the mean so the range of the data would be about $6$ standard deviations; $760-135=625$ and then $625/6=104.17$. Now this is where I get confused: in my solutions manual it says that the next step is using the Empirical Rule to figure out that $95 \%$ of the observations are within $2$ standard deviations of the mean;$625/4=156.25$. How did they come to this conclusion? Why do I need to divide the $625$ by $6$ and then by $4$?

Comment: Chebyshev's Inequality is a $theorem$, true for every distribution or sample having a mean and variance. The Empirical Rule is an $approximate\; rule\; of\; thumb,$ roughly true for many samples, especially those that come from normal populations. (The Empirical Rule is exactly true for a normal population.)

Answer (score 0):

By the Empirical Rule, 68% of the observations fall within 1 standard deviation of the mean, 95% of the observations fall within 2 standard deviations of the mean, and 99.7% (nearly all) of the observations fall within 3 standard deviations of the mean. All of the data fall between the smallest observation and the largest observation. Therefore, the 99.7% rule (and not the 95% rule) is applicable. (The 95% rule would be more appropriate if given, say, the *second* smallest observation and the *second* largest observation.)

According to the 99.7% rule, nearly all of the observations fall within 3 standard deviations of the mean; i.e., the range of the data set is approximately 6 standard deviations: If $R$ is the range and $\sigma$ the standard deviation, then $$R \approx 6 \sigma.$$ Solving for $\sigma$, $$\sigma \approx \frac{R}{6}.$$ In this case, $R = 760 - 135 = 625$; therefore, $\sigma \approx \frac{625}{6}$ by the Empirical Rule.

The answer from application of the Empirical Rule is the same as the one from application of Chebyshev's inequality. I assume the author of the textbook, finding the result uninteresting, opted to apply the 95% rule instead of the (arguably more appropriate) 99.7% rule.

With the name of the textbook, we might be able to shed more light on the author's reasoning.